# crontab launched many python processes to execute the task

Tags: python, process, cron

I scheduled a task in crontab, which is this:
* */8 * * * source /etc/profile && /usr/bin/python /home/rd/works/browser_testing/BrowserScript/src/miuibrowser/models/video_tasks.py

but when I check the process stauts, there always many processes are executed, and always received many reports.
In my mind, there should be only 1 process exist, and only received one reports.

Is there any advices?

Thanks,
Yong

Answer (score 0):

There're many tool to check if the process exit then do nothing, otherwise do your command, 
Example:
flock:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/f.lock {your_command} --minutely
```

or run-one, lockrun ... etc

Ps: https://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running